# My flask selenium Firefox geckodriver not working in heroku

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, geckodriver

I deployed flask app using selenium Firefox geckodriver in heroku use this method [heroku-integrated-firefox-geckodriver](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/pyronlaboratory/heroku-integrated-firefox-geckodriver)

But I got this error

```
> 2022-01-13T13:23:47.014999+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/insta/bot.py:37:
> DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass
> in a Service object
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.015013+00:00 app[web.1]:   self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,executable_path=os.environ.get("GECKODRIVER_PATH"),
> firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary(os.environ.get("FIREFOX_BIN")))
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.015054+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/insta/bot.py:37: DeprecationWarning: firefox_binary has been deprecated, please pass in
> a Service object
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.015054+00:00 app[web.1]:   self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,executable_path=os.environ.get("GECKODRIVER_PATH"),
> firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary(os.environ.get("FIREFOX_BIN")))
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.522706+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/instalogin" host=i-bot-1.herokuapp.com
> request_id=6329825e-962c-46c0-834e-d8966a927d29 fwd="42.106.180.246"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=512ms status=500 bytes=2182
> protocol=https
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520605+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-13 13:23:47,519] ERROR in app: Exception on /instalogin [POST]
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520615+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520616+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
> 2073, in wsgi_app
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520616+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520617+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
> 1518, in full_dispatch_request
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520617+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520618+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
> 1516, in full_dispatch_request
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520618+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520618+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
> 1502, in dispatch_request
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520619+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520619+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 29, in wrap
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520620+00:00 app[web.1]:     return f(*args, **kwargs)
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520620+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 88, in instalogin
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520620+00:00 app[web.1]:     bot = Bot(user)
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520621+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/insta/bot.py", line 37, in __init__
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520621+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,executable_path=os.environ.get("GECKODRIVER_PATH"),
> firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary(os.environ.get("FIREFOX_BIN")))
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520622+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
> line 174, in __init__
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520622+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.service.start()
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520623+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 98, in start
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520623+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.assert_process_still_running()
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520625+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 110, in assert_process_still_running
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520626+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise WebDriverException(
>     
>     2022-01-13T13:23:47.520626+00:00 app[web.1]: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service
> /app/vendor/geckodriver/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code
> was: 64
```

[image]

This is my code and this is my selenium code.
This code perfectly working in my local computer.

```
        import os
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
        from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary            

        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        options.add_argument("-no-sandbox")
        user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16"
        options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)

        bot = webdriver.Firefox(options=options,executable_path=os.environ.get("GECKODRIVER_PATH"), firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary(os.environ.get("FIREFOX_BIN")))
        bot.set_window_size(500, 950)
```

I don't know why it's not working. I tried so many another methods but it's not working, please help.